# Configure netplan to add routing policy automatically with DHCP interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routing, netplan

I have a fleet of devices using Ubuntu 22.04 and netplan, which have two interfaces (wired and wireless), both receiving IP addresses from DHCP. Due to the usage pattern of these devices, pretty often both interfaces would be online and have access to the Internet.

I want to create a routing table with a default route for each interface, so if process X (e.g., ping) uses interface A as a source for network activity, packets would go through interface A and its gateway.

Currently, I can achieve it by manually creating route tables and setting the lookup rule like this:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 table 1
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 2
ip rule add from 10.0.0.2 lookup 1
ip rule add from 192.168.0.2 lookup 2
```

But I want to do it automatically, with a dynamic interface source and gateway.

Is it possible to specify in the netplan configuration to create/use route tables for DHCP interfaces? I've seen examples for static interfaces, but cannot configure them for dynamic.

P.S. I guess I can make it work using routable.d custom script, but is there a way to define it in netplan yaml or at least is there any well-known and stable script/software/solution for this?